# Assessing Proportional Hazards Assumption of a Cox Model with Caseweights

Tags: cox-model, survey-weights, schoenfeld-residuals

I have data that I have used the R package twang with multinomial propensity scoring, to assign caseweights based on an ATT model. Once these caseweights have been assigned, they are typically used with a survey procedure. In R, there is the survey package which contains svycoxph, but this can also be done using the survival package with + cluster(id) in the model, to compute robust standard errors (gives same result for my caseweights).

I am have satisfactorily fit the non-propensity scored data as such, after reviewing cox.zph test and the Schoenfeld residual plots:

```
> coxph1 <- coxph(Surv(time,status) ~ x1 + x2 + age + tt(age), 
data=data, tt=function(x,t,...) x * log(t))

> cox.zph(coxph1)
            rho    chisq     p
x1      -0.0306     1.54 0.215
x2      -0.0367     2.21 0.137
age     -0.5752 37284.88 0.000
tt(age)  0.5789 48667.57 0.000
GLOBAL       NA 48676.43 0.000
```

x1 and x2 are categorical (1=yes, 0=no) predictors.

I have removed some variables for simplicity of explanation, disregard the age variable.

When I fit a model using the weights and robust standard error measurement, I am concerned that the use of the weights are obscuring the cox.zph and Schoenfeld plots:

```
> coxph2 <- coxph(Surv(time,status)~ x1 + x2 + age + tt(age) + cluster(id), weights=w, data=data, tt=function(x,t,...) x * log(t))
> cox.zph(coxph2)
           rho   chisq                   p
x1       0.182    60.1 0.00000000000000888
x2      -0.128    42.5 0.00000000006934375
age     -0.581 54338.6 0.00000000000000000
tt(age)  0.586 70624.8 0.00000000000000000
GLOBAL      NA 70734.7 0.00000000000000000
```

The Schoenfeld plots look accordingly bad. [image]

This gets even worse as more predictors are added (in terms of how it looks in comparison to the unweighted version).

Side question:
x1 has a maximum follow up time of 60, whereas x2 and the reference category have follow up to 100 months. Is there any chance this is having an impact on the caseweights/their relation to the residual?

This issue persists if using the survey package and svycox.

I have two questions:
1) Is there in fact an issue with using caseweights and or robust SE estimation in how the Schoenfeld residual is constructed, and should these be avoided?
2) If 1 is true, is there another preferred method for testing the PH assumption? So far, I have been adding a time transformation tt() for each and seeing if that is significant, but that is far from an ideal approach. The only other alternative I see is to treat those that violate the assumption in the unweighted model the same way in the weighted model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

I think I have found a solution to the problem.
I edited the original cox.zph function to included weighted Schoenfeld residuals:

Here was the original:

```
cox.zph <- function(fit, transform='km', global=TRUE) {
call <- match.call()
if (!inherits(fit, 'coxph')) stop ("Argument must be the result of coxph")
if (inherits(fit, 'coxph.null'))
stop("The are no score residuals for a Null model")

sresid <- resid(fit, 'schoenfeld')
varnames <- names(fit$coefficients)
nvar <- length(varnames)
ndead<- length(sresid)/nvar
if (nvar==1) times <- as.numeric(names(sresid))
else         times <- as.numeric(dimnames(sresid)[[1]])
```

And the change:

```
cox.zph <- function(fit, transform='km', global=TRUE) {
call <- match.call()
if (!inherits(fit, 'coxph')) stop ("Argument must be the result of coxph")
if (inherits(fit, 'coxph.null'))
stop("The are no score residuals for a Null model")

sresid <- resid(fit, 'schoenfeld', **weighted=TRUE**)
varnames <- names(fit$coefficients)
nvar <- length(varnames)
ndead<- length(sresid)/nvar
if (nvar==1) times <- as.numeric(names(sresid))
else         times <- as.numeric(dimnames(sresid)[[1]])
```

Does anyone see potential problems with solution? It appears to have made both the zph test and the scaled schoenfeld residual plots much more reasonable.

Comment: You were focusing on weights but your model has a `tt` component and the code of `cox.zph` says: "stop("function not defined for models with tt() terms")". And as I understand the situation, the express purpose of `tt` terms is to allow management of certain kinds on non-proportionality.I think you would get further information in Therneau & Grampsch, ch 6 sect 5.